# No access to Internet after uninstalling Tor

Tags: internet, tor

I uninstalled Tor, it seems like I didn't cleared it correctly, 
I tried this for uninstalling

'$ sudo apt-get purge tor vidalia tor-dbg torsocks torchat tor-geo* tor-arm redsocks onioncat obfsproxy anon-proxy deb.torproject.org-keyring
$ sudo reboot'

Now I don't have internet, I tried so many things, but didn't worked for me,
Here is something I think might help you out.

'enp8s0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        ether 28:d2:44:38:b7:14  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4131  bytes 258890 (258.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4131  bytes 258890 (258.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp9s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c666:13a4:ec2d:6546  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether a4:db:30:74:8a:18  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 674  bytes 58855 (58.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 866  bytes 95542 (95.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0'
The result of route -n

'Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp9s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp9s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp9s0'

I'm posting with my mobile phone, pardon me for formatting problems, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

When you configured tor(a_proxy_based_network). You have also made it to channel every outgoing packets from the browser or connections through port 9050 or what ever your choice is.So if you are using FoxyProxy make sure to use the "Default URL".And if you are using another Proxy Setting make sure to reset it.